# What is good architecture for an insert that fails due to locked records and retrying the insert?

Tags: after-trigger

I have tried to exhaustion on avoiding the locked records but it seems that I have an account that is added to opportunity partners so frequently, that often multiple users are creating deals that use the same Account on the partner object at the same time. (it locks the Account because of master detail relationship and roll up fields).

I have an after Insert trigger that updates the opportunity team but it fails for a certain Account about 10% of the time. It does not fail for 95% of the opportunities, however, these 5% are becoming a problem.

What I am trying to do is do a try on insert of the team and if it fails run some other future or batch class based on failed records. But before I do this, I hope to get some help.

Note; locking records via a query does not help. If I have 3 users creating 3 deals with this account at the same time, locking causes errors on the 2. I know it sound odd, but I have tested this and locking does not stop the errors.

Comment: You are on right track. Creating a failed record object and then running regular batch jobs on the object will help.

Comment: This is mostly likely to be caused by a larger problem under the hood. Without getting into explicit details, have you checked if there is a data skew and sharing recalculation leading to this issue? In other words, is this happening only on specific account records (*i.e. associating oppty with specific accounts*)? If yes, what is the # of child record count for these accounts & what about the sharing defined for these accounts? Think if too many child records and too many sharing recalculation is holding the lock on these accounts for a longer duration.

Comment: If your problem fits into the previous comment, then you should start thinking on the lines of redesigning the data access and relationship (because no amount of code optimization is likely to help you out resolve this situation).

Comment: @arut I will look at that but our current sharing model edit for all users. This will change and could make the issue bigger.      .... .. What I am thinking is creating exception accounts for the Class to run. We need to update account teams often but the large volume accounts don't really need it and we can do that manually. This should reduce the locking of those accounts. But I will look at your point because we are changing our sharing models and doing a global implementation.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about excluding these few accounts being processed by the class (conditional logic), right?

Comment: @arut Correct. There are about a dozen accounts that really don't change teams and if they do, it can be managed manually very easily. The other accounts do have changes frequently and we need updated teams on accounts. We use Territory Managment to manage the teams but the Opportunity Teams do not access this (They do on the End User Level but on the partner level) So TerrManag drives AccTeam which drives OppTeam. Although we have public sharing today, that will be different in 6 months so having a cleaner process makes sense.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll think through few other things that would be helpful for troubleshooting this scenario. Regardless, you should start with one problematic account and work your way back to the problem (I guess you are already doing that).